# Implicit differentiation problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The equation of a curve C is given by $x^3 + xy + 2y^2 = k $

If $C$ has a tangent which is parallel to the $y$ axis , show that the $y$ coordinate of the point of contact of the tangent with $C$ must satisfy the equation

$$-64y^3 - 2y^2 - k = 0 $$

My attempt -

$$\frac{dy}{dx} (x^3 + xy + 2y^2 = k ) = \frac{-3x^2 -y}{x+4y} $$

The tangent of C is $x= _____ $ as its parallel to $y$ axis

So , my understanding is that, in the point of interception, the gradients of the Two equation must be the same and that's how I show it .

But how do I find the gradient for

$-64y^3 - 2y^2 - k = 0 $

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that the tangent is of the form $x = a$, meaning it is a vertical line. This means that the slope of the tangent is $"\infty"$, unlike a horizontal tangent which has a slope of $0$.

So what does this mean?

We have the derivative as you showed: $$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{-3x^2-y}{x+4y}$$

For this to be infinite, we require the denominator to be equal to $0$ and the numerator to be anything but $0$.

We solve:

$$x+4y = 0 \Rightarrow x = -4y$$

Now we can plug this into the original equation:

$$x^3+xy+2y^2=k \Rightarrow (-4y)^3 + (-4y)y + 2y^2 = k \Rightarrow -64y^3 -4y^2+2y^2=k$$

Simplifying, we have:

$$-64y^3-2y^2=k\Rightarrow -64y^3-2y^2-k=0$$

as required.

Comment: Seeking for zero needs simpler calculations than seeking for infinity. :)

Comment: @CiaPan You make a valid point that I had not thought about. I guess I just approached it w.r.t to $y$ because that is how the OP was approaching it. +1 to your answer though.

Comment: Thank you. That was an example of looking at the problem from another side. From the other side of the sheet of paper, to be precise. :)

Answer (score 1):

The tangent parallel to $y$ axis implies the function $x(y)$ has a zero derivative at the point of tangency. Hence you differentiate wrt. $y$:
$$x^3 + xy + 2y^2 = k \quad \left| \frac d{dy}\right.$$
$$3x^2\,x' + x'y + x + 4y = 0$$
Vanishing derivative of $x$ wrt. $y$ means $x'=\frac {dx}{dy}=0$, so:
$$x + 4y = 0$$
Plug it to the given equation:
$$(-4y)^3 + (-4y)y + 2y^2 = k$$
and you'll get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since the tangent is parallel to the $y$-axis (the tangent is a vertical line $x=a$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$), you have $x+4y=0$ in your derivative. Simply substitute $x=-4y$ into the equation of the curve $C$ and you will arrive at the result.